# dash/plotly multiple dropdowns within datatable based on another column value

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

is it possible (and if so how can this be done) to have dropdowns inside a datable where the items in the dropdowns are based on the entry made by the user in another column?

For instance, assume I have an editable datatable with 3 columns (and  a fixed number of rows say 4): ticker, expiry and strike. The ticker column is editable and is used as an input cell. The column expiry would be a dropdown which items depend on the input in column ticker. Finally the column strike would be a dropdown which items would be based on columns ticker and expiry.

The relations between ticker and expiry on one hand and ticker-expiry and strike on the other hand are stored and can be retrieved in a dataframe format.

I guess I would need a callback based on the edited row (column ticker) in order to add items to the dropdown of the same row in column expiry. Then based on what has been selected in the dropdown from the expiry column another column to populate the dropdown in column strike (?)

From [the docs](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/dropdowns), the dropdowns are already defined within the layout/datatable declaration. In my case I would have empty dropdowns at start but whenever a specific cell is edited then the dropdown in the next column on the same row would be populated.

Edit: using the docs as example:

```
app = Dash(__name__)

df = pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict([
    ('climate', ['Sunny', 'Snowy', 'Sunny', 'Rainy']),
    ('temperature', [13, 43, 50, 30]),
    ('city', ['NYC', 'Montreal', 'Miami', 'NYC'])
]))

app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='table-dropdown',
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        columns=[
            {'id': 'climate', 'name': 'climate'},
            {'id': 'temperature', 'name': 'temperature'},
            {'id': 'city', 'name': 'city', 'presentation': 'dropdown'},
        ],
        editable=True,
        dropdown={
            'city': {
                 'options': [
                    {'label': i, 'value': i}
                    for i in df['city'].unique()
                ]
            }
        }
    ),
    html.Div(id='table-dropdown-container')
])
```

Here the user would input something in column climate (Sunny, Snowy, Rainy or nothing or else) and via a callback the dropdown in column city would get populated based on a relational dataframe: if the user enters Snowy then the dropdown would show NYC or Montreal, if the user entered blank or something else than Snowy, Sunny, Rainy, the dropdown would remain blank/empty.

Hopefully this makes sense...